# Issues using dependencies with g++

Tags: c++, boost, g++, ld

I have some serious issues when linking to other libraries with g++, it often frustrates me to hell and stops me before I'm even started.

For example: I was just using boost.asio, trying out the tutorials. I found in the doc that I had to link to boost_system and regex, but for some reason I also had to add pthread for it to work ... I have installed boost with 'apt-get install', thinking all I would have to link to was boost. Wrong apparently ...

It seems I really can't understand how to develop on linux. How can you know when you need to add a library? In the example I gave, boost depends on pthread, so I have to link it. Why don't I have to link to any other stuff boost depends on? Or suppose pthread depends on something, why don't I have to link that (eg. why don't you have to link to standard C libs)? How can you know how g++ is configured? And how can you change it?

I guess my main question is: Is there any logic to configuring a build on linux? (useful references are always welcome also)

Just a last point of frustration:  it always seems to me programming is a LOT more fun and WAY easier than actually getting to it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to packaging bugs. If a library A depends on library B, that A should link against B. Your application only has to link against A.

Sometimes the packager of a library for some distro gets it wrong. Nothing you can do about that, really. For example, when I link against boost_system on Gentoo Linux, I don't have to link against pthread since boost_system links against pthread on its own:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/libboost_system.so | grep pthread
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcf677f8000)
```

Comment: I'll accept, since this is useful info. But it's still a bit vague to me why a shared lib would have some of its dependencies set and not others, how did they manage to build it in the first place if there is a dependency missing? And suppose I decide to build a lib from source, and it generates shared libs, will they contain this automatic linking information or is this some packaging detail?

Comment: @user1896048 Shared libraries can be built even if you don't link against their dependent libraries. That's because missing symbols are only checked when building executables. When building object files, this isn't checked (libraries are object file collections.) If you build from source, then if the creator of the library's build system is responsible for getting all link flags correctly. If they didn't, you can still influence it manually (usually, depending on the build system used) by adding `-l` entries to `LDFLAGS`. That last step is probably what the Debian packager missed.